# How does an external JavaScript tag access a another js files functions?

Tags: javascript

I have seen two `.js` files one containing

```
object.variable = (function(){
//some functions init() is defined here
//returns init
})();
```

Then within a `.html` file within script tags

```
$(document).ready(function(){object.variable.init()})
```

However, in the `.html` file there is no reference explicitly to that `.js` file, but the `.html` file can call the `init()`

Can someone explain to me how that is possible? Also how is a `document.ready` event handled inside a function expression?

Answer (score 0):

All JavaScript files that are loaded on one page got the same global scope:

```
 <script>
   var a = 1;
   window.b = 1;
 </script>
 <script>
  console.log(
   a,
   b
  );
 </script>
```

Using the global scope is usually a bad thing, as it makes the code hard to track (as you said: there is no explicit reference). Additionally any script that you include can access everything, so be careful which libraries  you use. Therefore I wouldn't adopt that pattern, instead use the `import` / `export` syntax and bundlers.

> Also how is a document.ready event handled inside a function expression?

Thats not the document `ready` event. It is a jQuery event handler. [doc](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)